# ViewImage change based on user input

Tags: android

i am currently trying change a imageView in my program, it needs to changed based what the user picks from the screen before, so i was wondering how i can access an image in my drawable folder through a string path?

all the examples i have seen have been either hard coded (R.drawable.XXX) or asking for the integer id value

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Make a HashMap using your string as a key and ID as a value.